# How do I share a Multi-Printer as lpr port on windows server 2012?

Tags: printing, windows-server-2012

I have a printer connected to my windows 2012 server and would like to share it so that other devices can print and scan from it using an lpr port

Is this possible?

Comment: Additional information might get an answer. Make/Model of device for example.

Comment: Its a Epson SX218. But i dont see why the brand/model matter. I assumed i needed to find someway in windows to share it.

Comment: The *scan from it* and *using an* [DOS] *LPR port* will get quite interesting.

Comment: If thats not possible, what other options are there to share a scanner over network ?

Comment: No idea on the scanning. For the printing part I posted an answer which I assume will work on server 2008. I have no server 2008 to test it on though, but win7 and vista are probably close enough.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the scan part and that DOS printing should die one of these day. (Preferably when you get a chance to migrate away from win95 and win98 age applications), this is how you set up a LPR port.

Go to [start] [Control panel] and select "Devices and printers"
Then right click on the local printer you want to share and select properties.

[image]

[image]

Click on ports, then on add ports. (Note this will not work on all printers).

[image]

Select "Standard TCP/IP port" and click on the [New port] button.

Click [Next] and add the name of the printer. (If you do not have a proper DNS name you can work around it by using an IP, or just add the printers MAC to the DHCP reservations and save yourself a lot of trouble in the future).

Next choose a printer name.  "E.g. Finance_hp_4000_LPR".
Click [Next]

On the next screen use "Custom setting" rather then the "standard generic network card"
Procotol: Select LPR,
LPR settings: Select Input LP1.
Click on [OK], [Next], [Finish], [Close] and [Apply]